# No preview in wordpress media section

Tags: wordpress, thumbnails, preview

I updated my wordpress system to the latest version (5.4).

Since that update my media section contains only white fields.

If I click on one of the picture files I can see the correct storage path on my server but still no preview. If I click on “edit” the picture is shown. Everything works perfect on the website itself. But it’s hard to work in the backend, if you can’t see any preview.

I already checked the filesystem permissions (755) and forced a thumbnail regeneration without any success.

Actually I have no more idea, what else I can do to get my media section working correctly. 
Thanks for hints.

Comment: Do you have any errors in your server log? Any errors in your dev console? This could be anything - a plugin conflict, core error, etc.

Comment: I have only one error. But I think that's not the problem:PHP Deprecated:  Function create_function() is deprecated in /var/www/dbrsp.de/wp-content/plugins/wp-memory-usage/wp-memory-usage.php on line 108
[06-Apr-2020 22:06:29 UTC] PHP Notice:  A non well formed numeric value encountered in /var/www/dbrsp.de/wp-content/plugins/wp-memory-usage/wp-memory-usage.php on line 56

Comment: I figured out, I have a cURL error 28. Could that be a reason for my problems?

Answer (score 0):

got my images back. The WP Update changed the site URL from https://.... to http://... that is blocked by fw. After changing back everything works fine.